# Find: Use regex to get all files with specific directory name in path, but without another specific directory name in path

Tags: command-line, find, regular-expression

I'm trying to use find to return all file names that have a specific directory in their path, but don't have another specific directory anywhere in the file path. Something like:

```
myRegex= <regex> 
targetDir= <source directory>
find $targetDir -regex $myRegex -print
```

I know I might also be able to do this by piping one find command into another, but I would like to know how to do this with a single regular expression.

For example, I want every file that has the directory "good" in it's path, but doesn't have the directory "bad" anywhere in its path no matter the combination. Some examples:

```
/good/file_I_want.txt #Captured
/good/bad/file_I_dont_want.txt #Not captured

/dir1/good/file_I_want.txt #Captured
/dir2/good/bad/file_I_dont_want.txt #Not captured

/dir1/good/dir2/file_I_want.txt #Captured
/dir1/good/dir2/bad/file_I_want.txt #Not captured

/bad/dir1/good/file_I_dont_want.txt #Not captured
```

Keep in mind some file names might contain "good" or "bad", but I only want to account for directory names.

```
/good/bad.txt #Captured
/bad/good.txt #Not captured
```

My research suggests I should use a Negative Lookahead and a Negative Lookbehind. However, nothing I have tried has worked so far. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Inian said, you don't need `-regex` (which is non standard, and the syntax varies greatly between the implementations that do support `-regex`¹).

You can use `-path` for that, but you can also tell `find` not to enter directories called `bad`, which would be more efficient than discovering every file in them for later filtering them out with `-path`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name bad -prune -o -path '*/good/*.txt' -type f -print
```

(`LC_ALL=C` so `find`'s `*` wildcard doesn't choke on filenames with sequence of bytes not forming valid characters in the locale).

Or for more than one folder name:

```
LC_ALL=C find . '(' -name bad -o -name worse ')' -prune -o \
  '(' -path '*/good/*' -o -path '*/better/*' ')' -name '*.txt' -type f -print
```

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
print -rC1 -- (^bad/)#*.txt~^*/good/*(ND.)
```

```
print -rC1 -- (^(bad|worse)/)#*.txt~^*/(good|better)/*(ND.)
```

Or for the lists in arrays:

```
good=(good better best)
bad=(bad worse worst)
print -rC1 -- (^(${(~j[|])bad})/)#*.txt~^*/(${(~j[|])good})/*(ND.)
```

To *not* descend into dirs called `bad`, or (less efficient like with `-path '*/good/*' ! -path '*/bad/*'`):

```
print -rC1 -- **/*.txt~*/bad/*~^*/good/*(ND.)
```

In `zsh -o extendedglob`, `~` is the *except* (and-not) globbing operator while `^` is the negation operator and `#` is 0-or-more-of-the-preceding-thing like regexp `*`. `${(~j[|])array}` joins the elements of the array with `|`, with that `|` being treated as a glob operator instead of a literal `|` with `~`.

In `zsh`, you'd be able to use PCRE matching after `set -o rematchpcre`:

```
set -o rematchpcre
regex='^(?!.*/bad/).*/good/.*\.txt\Z'
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND.e['[[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]]'])
```

But that evaluation of shell code for every file (including those in `bad` directories) is likely to make it a lot slower than other solutions.

Also beware that PCRE (contrary to zsh globs) would choke on sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale, and doesn't support multi-byte charsets other than UTF-8. Fixing the locale to `C` like for `find` above would address both for this particular pattern.

If you'd rather `[[ =~ ]]` only does extended regexp matching like in `bash`, you can also instead just load the pcre module (`zmodload zsh/pcre`) and use `[[ -pcre-match ]]` instead of `[[ =~ ]]` to do PCRE matching.

Or you could do the filtering with `grep -zP` (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
regex='^(?!.*/bad/).*/good/.*\.txt\Z'
find . -type f -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C grep -zPe "$regex" |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

(though `find` still discovers all files in all `bad` directories).

Replace `tr '\0' '\n'` with `xargs -r0 cmd` if you need to do anything with those files (other than printing them one per line).

---

<sup>¹ In any case, I don't know any `find` implementation that supports perl-like or vim-like regular expressions which you'd need for look-around operators.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. How would you deal with more folder names than "good"? For example, can I match for both "good" and "goods" folders? What if I wanted to match "good" and "better"?

Comment: @Teatree, see edit.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a regex for this, you can use the `-path` predicate to exclude directories with a specific name at any level

```bsh
find . -type f -path '*/good/*' '!' -path '*/bad/*'
```

Comment: better enclose the bang between single quotes to avoid the shell's (bash?) expansion : `'!'`

Comment: Or escape it: `\!` (one less keystroke if you're typing)

Comment: useful suggestions! updated

Answer (score 2):

While it's likely less-efficient (though I'm not certain!) and less "correct" than `find`'s powerful filtering (for example naive `grep` here will not work for names containing newline chars, though these are extremely rare and normally represent an error), it's often much easier to stack a few instances of `grep` which successively filter the results using simpler matches and inverse matches `-v`

This takes more caution around substrings to ensure you're really finding a directory name, but generally will give a much easier syntax to understand and may do all that you need!

```bsh
find ./ | grep "/good/" | grep -v "/bad/" | grep '\.txt$'
```

Comment: oh, TMYK! cheers, let met tidy that up

Comment: cheers! I've updated my Answer to incorporate both; specifically, I want to convey the idea that this is both not as good, but the perfection often doesn't matter if the environment can be asserted or assumed not to have some collection of (evil) edge cases

Comment: Thanks. It's perfectly acceptable to post answers with limitations as long as they are enunciated so the reader can take an educated decision about it. Welcome to Unix.SE btw!

Comment: Here, as I showed in my answer, one usual way to deal with file arbitrary file paths with text utilities if on GNU systems at least is to use NUL-delimited records instead of newline delimited records as NUL contrary to NL can't be found in a file path.